# Ошибка NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdbc, зависимости

В общем, суть вполне ясна, по какой-то причине не хочет добавлять нужную зависимость.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Я пробовал все версии, пробовал реимпорт, гугл молчит. Все равно в папке META-INF/lib нужной джарки нет. Я подозреваю, что дело в каком-то конфликте зависимостей но не имею понятия как это решить. Прошу помощи

Pom файл

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.dikhim</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <jsf.version>2.2.8</jsf.version>
        <primefaces.version>6.0</primefaces.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ web-primefaces ---
    [INFO] org.dikhim:web-primefaces:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.2.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
    [INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.10:compile
    [INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
    [INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
    [INFO] |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
    [INFO] |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
    [INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
    [INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
    [INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.2.8:compile
    [INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.2.8:compile
    [INFO] \- org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:6.0:compile
```

Comment: Приведите ваш pom файл целиком +(если получится) дерево dependency

Comment: @Chubatiy добавил

Comment: Укажите одинаковую версию spring.version для всех зависимостей(то есть, если вам надо jdbc 5.1.5.RELEASE  - то такое и укажите для всех). И тогда у вас сама она подтянется(у вас же в pom уже есть spring jdbc). Вы же заменяли текущую зависимость новой? Или просто добавляли поверх?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Если проект правильно сконфигурирован, то war соберется без проблем. Иначе придется добавлять в build секцию war плагин и явно прописывать пути к web ресурсам.

Comment: Во первых не работает, во вторых provided означает, что зависимость должна быть предоставлена сервером приложений, она гарантировано 
 не будет упакована. Если я все правильно понимаю

Comment: Действительно я все перепутал. (обновил ответ)

Comment: да. Точно. В какой-то момент потерял строчку. То есть до этого проект собирался силами самой idea и почему-то внезапно решил что какая-то зависимость лишняя